# How can I quote special characters contained inside XML tags?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, xml

is possible by simple way replace string (`sed`) limited inside 2 strings?

**Example**

I have `xml` feed contains many tags, including `<DESCRIPTION>` tag with special chars inside.

I need change special chars **only** inside this tag. I mean `<` to `&lt;`, `"` to `&quot;`, etc.

**Source**

```
    <DESCRIPTION><p>Konvice s pokličkou smalt je vhodná ke každodennímu použití. Lze ji mýt v myčce na nádobí a je vhodná pro plynové, elektrické sporáky a indukci. Objem 2 l, v červené barvě s bílým puntíkem.</p><p> </p><p> </p></DESCRIPTION>
```

**Result**

```
    <DESCRIPTION>&lt;p&gt;Konvice s pokličkou smalt je vhodná ke každodennímu použití. Lze ji mýt v myčce na nádobí a je vhodná pro plynové, elektrické sporáky a indukci. Objem 2 l, v červené barvě s bílým puntíkem.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;</DESCRIPTION>
```

Or is another way to "repair" this xml?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

It works, but for most of xml tags, even for xml head. :/

```
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt;
<SHOP><GENERATED>2021-02-05T14:15:02+01:00</GENERATED>
<SHOPITEM>

    <ITEM_ID>ABF644B</ITEM_ID>
    <PRODUCTNAME>L&Aacute;HEV NA VODU &quot;BISFREE ECO&quot; 550ML, HN&#282;D&Aacute;</PRODUCTNAME>
    <DESCRIPTION>L&aacute;hev na vodu &quot;Bisfree Eco&quot;. D&iacute;ky barevn&eacute; plastov&eacute; l&aacute;hvi na vodu lock budete m&iacute;t o mno&#382;stv&iacute; vypit&yacute;ch tekutin p&#345;ehled. Mal&aacute; velikost s objemem 550 ml s v&iacute;&#269;kem se toti&#382; vleze do ka&#382;d&eacute; ta&scaron;ky &#269;i kabelky a vodu tak m&#367;&#382;ete m&iacute;t st&aacute;le p&#345;i sob&#283;. L&aacute;hev je vyroben&aacute; z Tritanu -  lehk&yacute;, odoln&yacute; proti n&aacute;raz&#367;m a kvalitn&iacute; plast - neobsahuje BPA. Tritan je popul&aacute;rn&iacute; n&aacute;hra&#382;ka skla. Barva hn&#283;d&aacute;. Rozm&#283;ry - 6,5&times;6,5&times;22 cm</DESCRIPTION>
    <URL>https://b2b.utc.cz/lahev-na-vodu-bisfree-eco-550ml-hneda/347058p/</URL>
    <IMGURL>https://b2b.utc.cz/bin/product/4/ABF644B.jpg</IMGURL>
    <IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE></IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE>
    <ORIGINAL_PRICE_VAT>199.00</ORIGINAL_PRICE_VAT>
    <PURCHASE_PRICE_VAT>164.46</PURCHASE_PRICE_VAT>
    <MANUFACTURER>LOCKNLOCK</MANUFACTURER>
    <CATEGORY>STOLOV&Aacute;N&Iacute; | P&#344;&Iacute;PRAVA N&Aacute;POJ&#366; | SPORTOVN&Iacute; LAHVE</CATEGORY>
    <EAN>8803733138772</EAN>
    <ITEMGROUP_ID></ITEMGROUP_ID>
    <PRICE_VAT>199.00</PRICE_VAT>
</SHOPITEM>
<SHOPITEM>
    <ITEM_ID>ABF644G</ITEM_ID>
    <PRODUCTNAME>L&Aacute;HEV NA VODU &quot;BISFREE ECO&quot; 550ML, ZELEN&Aacute;</PRODUCTNAME>
    <DESCRIPTION>L&aacute;hev na vodu &quot;Bisfree Eco&quot;. D&iacute;ky barevn&eacute; plastov&eacute; l&aacute;hvi na vodu lock budete m&iacute;t o mno&#382;stv&iacute; vypit&yacute;ch tekutin p&#345;ehled. Mal&aacute; velikost s objemem 550 ml s v&iacute;&#269;kem se toti&#382; vleze do ka&#382;d&eacute; ta&scaron;ky &#269;i kabelky a vodu tak m&#367;&#382;ete m&iacute;t st&aacute;le p&#345;i sob&#283;. L&aacute;hev je vyroben&aacute; z Tritanu -  lehk&yacute;, odoln&yacute; proti n&aacute;raz&#367;m a kvalitn&iacute; plast - neobsahuje BPA. Tritan je popul&aacute;rn&iacute; n&aacute;hra&#382;ka skla. Barva zelen&aacute;. Rozm&#283;ry - 6,5&times;6,5&times;22 cm</DESCRIPTION>
    <URL>https://b2b.utc.cz/lahev-na-vodu-bisfree-eco-550ml-zelena/347057p/</URL>
    <IMGURL>https://b2b.utc.cz/bin/product/4/ABF644G.jpg</IMGURL>
    <IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE></IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE>
...
```

It should be.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SHOP><GENERATED>2021-02-05T14:19:48+01:00</GENERATED>
<SHOPITEM>
    <ITEM_ID>ABF644B</ITEM_ID>
    <PRODUCTNAME>LÁHEV NA VODU "BISFREE ECO" 550ML, HNĚDÁ</PRODUCTNAME>
    <DESCRIPTION>&lt;p&gt;Konvice s pokličkou smalt je vhodná ke každodennímu použití. Lze ji mýt v myčce na nádobí a je vhodná pro plynové, elektrické sporáky a indukci. Objem 2 l, v červené barvě s bílým puntíkem.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;</DESCRIPTION>
    <URL>https://b2b.utc.cz/lahev-na-vodu-bisfree-eco-550ml-hneda/347058p/</URL>
    <IMGURL>https://b2b.utc.cz/bin/product/4/ABF644B.jpg</IMGURL>
    <IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE></IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE>
    <ORIGINAL_PRICE_VAT>199.00</ORIGINAL_PRICE_VAT>
    <PURCHASE_PRICE_VAT>164.46</PURCHASE_PRICE_VAT>
    <MANUFACTURER>LOCKNLOCK</MANUFACTURER>
    <CATEGORY>STOLOVÁNÍ | PŘÍPRAVA NÁPOJŮ | SPORTOVNÍ LAHVE</CATEGORY>
    <EAN>8803733138772</EAN>
    <ITEMGROUP_ID></ITEMGROUP_ID>
    <PRICE_VAT>199.00</PRICE_VAT>
</SHOPITEM>
...
```

Comment: Why are comments removed?

Comment: I did'nt remove them, I posted an updated answer but it was wrong, that's why I deleted it. I'm still working on it, I will tell you when I get it.

Comment: I think adding a "\" before the characters should work.

Comment: They're called 'HTML entities' or 'entity encoding'. It's not clear in your example, do you want to entity-encode the contents of the XML tags? Where are you getting the XML from, maybe encode it before you put it in the tags? Is this on a webserver, what languages (PHP?) do you have available. If it's just one file then cut-paste using a website with [a html-entity encoder](https://coderstoolbox.net/string/#!encoding=xml&action=encode&charset=us_ascii) will be quicker than writing/finding a script!

Comment: @genderbee I think I got it, but you would have to try with the real thing.

Comment: A [.net solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157646/best-way-to-encode-text-data-for-xml).

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you need to install the `recode` package:

```
sudo apt install recode
```

**Make a backup of the original file**.

---

I have achieved this so far:

The code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# create a function to parse the files
f() {
  # get the original text between the tags inside DESCRIPTION
  decoded="$(sed -n '/<DESCRIPTION>/p;' "$1" | sed 's:<\([^>]*\)>::g' | sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*\|[[:blank:]]*$//g')"

  # get the encoded text from the decoded text
  encoded="$(echo "$decoded" | recode ..html | sed 's:&lt;DESCRIPTION&gt;\(.*\)&lt;/DESCRIPTION&gt;:\1:')"

  # encode everything inside DESCRIPTION to temporal file
  awk '/DESCRIPTION/{"echo \""$0"\" | recode ..html" | getline $0;}1' "$1" > output.xml

  # replace the encoded with the decoded
  [[ ! -z "$encoded" ]] && sed -i "s/$encoded/$decoded/" output.xml

  # decode DESCRIPTION tags
  sed "s:&lt;\([^;]*\)DESCRIPTION&gt;:<\1DESCRIPTION>:g" output.xml >> result.xml 
}

# create result file
> result.xml

# split the source file into <SHOPITEM> chunks
csplit --suffix-format="%d.FOO" file.xml '/<SHOPITEM>/' '{*}' 2>&1 > /dev/null

# loop over the "chunk" files
for i in *.FOO; do
  # apply the function to the "chunk" file
  f "$i"
  # remove "chunk" file
  rm "$i"
done

# remove temporal file
rm output.xml
```

Then:

```sh
$ cat result.xml
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SHOP><GENERATED>2021-02-05T14:19:48+01:00</GENERATED>
<SHOPITEM>
    <ITEM_ID>ABF644B</ITEM_ID>
    <PRODUCTNAME>LÁHEV NA VODU "BISFREE ECO" 550ML, HNĚDÁ</PRODUCTNAME>
    <DESCRIPTION>&lt;p&gt;Konvice s pokličkou smalt je vhodná ke každodennímu použití. Lze ji mýt v myčce na nádobí a je vhodná pro plynové, elektrické sporáky a indukci. Objem 2 l, v červené barvě s bílým puntíkem.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;</DESCRIPTION>
    <URL>https://b2b.utc.cz/lahev-na-vodu-bisfree-eco-550ml-hneda/347058p/</URL>
    <IMGURL>https://b2b.utc.cz/bin/product/4/ABF644B.jpg</IMGURL>
    <IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE></IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE>
    <ORIGINAL_PRICE_VAT>199.00</ORIGINAL_PRICE_VAT>
    <PURCHASE_PRICE_VAT>164.46</PURCHASE_PRICE_VAT>
    <MANUFACTURER>LOCKNLOCK</MANUFACTURER>
    <CATEGORY>STOLOVÁNÍ | PŘÍPRAVA NÁPOJŮ | SPORTOVNÍ LAHVE</CATEGORY>
    <EAN>8803733138772</EAN>
    <ITEMGROUP_ID></ITEMGROUP_ID>
    <PRICE_VAT>199.00</PRICE_VAT>
</SHOPITEM>
```

Comment: Wait, I have two different outputs with the same command. Let me check.

Comment: I don't know what happened, I use another file and the problem vanished.

Comment: Hello, thank you, it works, but for most xml tags, even for xml head. :/ See my updated question please. Thank you.

Comment: @genderbee Oh, I see what's happening, let me work it a little more.

Comment: @genderbee Could you show me the output fo this command: `echo $LANG`?

Comment: @ schrodigerscatcuriosity `en_US.UTF-8`. Is it related to problem?

Comment: @genderbee I'm not sure yet... but can be helpful.

Comment: Maybe useful info, I am using `LC_ALL=C sort -k 1n -t',' 5 > 6` in mys script, sometimes it works, sometime not (don't understand why). I can send you my whole script, if you want?

Comment: @genderbee Not right now, let me see if I can solve this first :)

Comment: Thanks very much, but at the end, I used CDATA.